# WPF: Animating a StaticResource updates other controls that use that resource

Tags: wpf, animation, resources, static

I have two TextBoxes that use the same StaticResource for their foreground colour.

When I apply an animation that changes the colour of the first TextBox, the colour on the second TextBox is also changed.

This does not happen if I don't use a StaticResource, so I am guessing that the animation is changing the colour of the brush defined in the resource, rather than the foreground colour on the first TextBox.

Here is the code I am using;

```
<Page.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBrush"
                     Color="Black" />

    <Storyboard x:Key="Glow"
                TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                Storyboard.TargetName="txt1">
        <ColorAnimation To="Blue"
                        Duration="0:0:0.1" />
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Normal"
                TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                Storyboard.TargetName="txt1">
        <ColorAnimation To="Yellow"
                        Duration="0:0:0.1" />
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Glow}" />
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Normal}" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </StackPanel.Triggers>

    <TextBlock Name="txt1"
               Foreground="{StaticResource TextBrush}">Text One</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Name="txt2"
               Foreground="{StaticResource TextBrush}">Text Two</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Is there anyway around this?

Matt

Answer (score 3):

By using a single `StaticResource` in the binding, changing the `Foreground` in your animation will change the resource itself.  This behavior is by design, as anything else would require full copies of resources, which would very much reduce the usefulness and benefits of using `StaticResource` in the first place.

The easy workaround, of course, is to not use a `StaticResource` here, or to use a separate resource per TextBox.

Comment: Or possibly just set `x:Shared="False"` on the resource. Haven't validated that, though.

Comment: @Kent: "In WPF, the default x:Shared condition for resources is true. This condition means that any given resource request always returns the same instance."  I think it's just sharing a "reference" to the brush.  If Brush were a value type, this would work, but here, I don't *think* it will have an effect, since it's already set (by default). ;)